# Best way to open a socket in Python

Tags: python, networking, tcp

I want to open a TCP client socket in Python. Do I have to go through all the low-level BSD create-socket-handle / connect-socket stuff or is there a simpler one-line way?

Comment: [Python's socket module](http://docs.python.org/library/socket) should be helpful.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Opening sockets in python is pretty simple. You really just need something like this:

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect((address, port))
```

and then you can `send()` and `recv()` like any other socket

Answer (score 22):

OK, this code worked

```
s = socket.socket()
s.connect((ip,port))
s.send("my request\r")
print s.recv(256)
s.close()
```

It was quite difficult to work that out from the Python socket module documentation. So I'll accept The.Anti.9's answer.

Comment: For future reference, it's typically sound practice to  used a larger parameter for socket.recv() than 256 bytes. I've frequently seen 4096 used.

Comment: Yes, good idea junkforce. What I was really after was to read a line of text, I'm now using the makefile() function to buffer the received data which works a treat.

Comment: You forgot to check the return value of send.

Comment: for future readers: better to use `s.sendall` (os per @Jean-PaulCalderone comment)

Answer (score 10):

For developing portable network programs of any sort in Python, [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com) is quite useful. One of its benefits is providing a convenient layer above low-level socket APIs.

Comment: Twisted = overkill