# Testing socket connection in Python

Tags: python, sockets

This question will expand on: [Best way to open a socket in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68774/best-way-to-open-a-socket-in-python)
When opening a socket how can I test to see if it has been established, and that it did not timeout, or generally fail.

Edit:
I tried this:

```
try:
    s.connect((address, '80'))
except:
    alert('failed' + address, 'down')
```

but the alert function is called even when that connection should have worked.

Comment: You should always use print_exc() from traceback module in except clause ! that will indicate accidental mistakes.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It seems that you catch not the exception you wanna catch out there :)

if the `s` is a `socket.socket()` object, then the right way to call `.connect` would be:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
address = '127.0.0.1'
port = 80  # port number is a number, not string
try:
    s.connect((address, port)) 
    # originally, it was 
    # except Exception, e: 
    # but this syntax is not supported anymore. 
except Exception as e: 
    print("something's wrong with %s:%d. Exception is %s" % (address, port, e))
finally:
    s.close()
```

Always try to see what kind of exception is what you're catching in a try-except loop.

You can check what types of exceptions in a socket module represent what kind of errors (timeout, unable to resolve address, etc) and make separate `except` statement for each one of them - this way you'll be able to react differently for different kind of problems.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working, even still, the alert function is not being called.

Comment: try to move the s.connect out of the try: block. what error will you get?

Comment: don't forget to close the socket after testing it is open.  :)

Comment: // , @kender, why did you choose the letter `s` as the variable name for the `socket.socket()` object? Is that an informal convention?

Comment: // , Also, do you think this Python example would work in Python 3.5?

Comment: @NathanBasanese I used `s` as the OP had this variable name in the question :)

Comment: @NathanBasanese for python3.5 - the socket part works. The `except Exception, e:` part is not supported anymore, it needs to be `except Exception as e:` instead. Edited the post to include that.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the function [connect_ex](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.connect_ex). It doesn't throw an exception. Instead of that, returns a C style integer value (referred to as [errno](http://linux.die.net/man/3/errno) in C):

```
s =  socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
result = s.connect_ex((host, port))
s.close()
if result:
    print "problem with socket!"
else:
    print "everything it's ok!"
```

Comment: In case of `result > 0` you will get the [`errno`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/errno.html) value of the failure. You can then do something like `print errno.errorcode[result]` to get a more useful hint about the failure.

Comment: Whether the connection is up or down: connect_ex() always return "0". It doesnt work for me

Answer (score 6):

You should really post:

1. The complete source code of your example
2. The **actual** result of it, not a summary

Here is my code, which works:

```
import socket, sys

def alert(msg):
    print >>sys.stderr, msg
    sys.exit(1)

(family, socktype, proto, garbage, address) = \
         socket.getaddrinfo("::1", "http")[0] # Use only the first tuple
s = socket.socket(family, socktype, proto)

try:
    s.connect(address) 
except Exception, e:
    alert("Something's wrong with %s. Exception type is %s" % (address, e))
```

When the server listens, I get nothing (this is normal), when it
doesn't, I get the expected message:

```
Something's wrong with ('::1', 80, 0, 0). Exception type is (111, 'Connection refused')
```

Comment: // , How does that bit with the `(family, socktype, proto, garbage, address) = \ ` assignment work? BTW, solid answer.

Comment: A hostname could have multiple IP-addresses - one should loop over all results of the `getaddrinfo`. But it should be invoked with the protocol ID so as to skip the UDP and like entries: `socket.getaddrinfo(address, port, 0, 0, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)`.

Answer (score 2):

12 years later for anyone having similar problems.

```
try:
    s.connect((address, '80'))
except:
    alert('failed' + address, 'down')
```

doesn't work because the port '80' is a string. Your port needs to be int.

```
try:
    s.connect((address, 80))
```

This should work.
Not sure why even the best answer didnt see this.

Comment: 12 years == better to use a `Context Manager ` vs `Try` and `Except`?