# Send full http requests using python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, httprequest

How would I send a full http request from a text file in python 2.7.

```
GET XXXXX HTTP/1.XXXXX
Host: XXXXX
User-Agent: XXXXX
Accept: XXXXX
Accept-Language: XXXXX
Accept-Encoding: XXXXX
Referer: XXXXX
DNT: XXXXX
Connection: close
Cookie: XXXXX
```

Say i have this written to a text file how would I send it in python 2.7 ([XXXXX] would be replaced with the information). And could I repeat it and send it multiple times.

Comment: Use python socket and send via it this file content.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/177389/1531971