# Send packets from one computer to another not on the same network

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, scapy

I wanted to know how to send packets from another computer on some network to another computer at different network.
I know the local IP of the computer and the public IP of the first network and I also know the local IP of the second computer and the public IP of the other computer's network.
How can I send packets (via scapy or via socket python)
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by opening a socket, using the public IP of the other computer and the port on which a server is listening:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68774/ddg#68796

Comment: And it's not possible with 2 ip's to send a packet?

Comment: You'll have to open a socket to each of the IP's.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can send ICMP to an ip :

```
pckt=IP(src=ip_src, dst=ip_dst)/ICMP()) # Creates the packet
send(pckt,  verbose=0) #sends it
```

Comment: Yes, it works only with 2 computers on the same network, I want in different network...

Comment: Have you defined the route to that different network?  Check with `netstat -rn`