# Process output of netcat and return back using python

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, subprocess, netcat

I run netcat to listen to a server in a bash shell:

```
nc domain.com 1234
```

The server outputs three numbers; I need to perform arithmetic on them and send the result back to the server.

I have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

nccommand = "nc domain.com 1234 > ncoutput.txt"
subprocess.Popen(nccommand, shell=True)

with open("ncoutput.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
lines = [x.strip() for x in lines]
lines = [int(x) for x in lines]

result = (lines[0]*lines[1])/lines[2]

*command to input result into the netcat stream goes here*
```

`ncouput.txt` isn't created until the netcat command is closed, which is problem because I need to have it open to stream the calculation result

Also, I'm not sure how to input a string into the command line whilst the netcat stream is still open. Should I just do `subprocess.Popen(numinput, shell=True)`?

Comment: Since you want to programmatically interact with a server via a socket, you probably don't want netcat at all. Just [open the socket in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68774/478288) and send/recv as needed.

Comment: @chrisaycock Managing to get it working using sockets, thanks for your help!